# Can I put custom events in the default event bus in AWS EventBridge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Can I call `PutEvents` on the `default` event bus of AWS EventBridge to push custom events?

I am trying at the moment but it doesn't seem to do anything (however I do not get an error). After reading a bit, I am doubting whether it is possible to put custom events on the default event bus.

Is it required to create a custom event bus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, see the first paragraph of this docs page https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/create-event-bus.html

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.